# Scheduled job not executing my PLSQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, jobs, schedule

I have a PLSQL block that is supposed to insert rows in a table and it works fine. I am trying to create a scheduled job on SQL Developer so that it can run the block, say every day.

I created the job and embedded the PLSQL block within it but it seems as if it isn't working.

There are no errors but nothing is being inserted in the table.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post your code to show us how you achieved your requirement,

Answer (score 1):

Verify the job status:

```
SELECT job_name, status, error#
FROM   user_scheduler_job_run_details
ORDER BY job_name;
```

Comment: Yes I checked and it was failing. However I fixed it by removing "/" from my job_action. Thank you tho.